# How to parse this JSON data skipping the three main nodes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to write JavaScript to parse this JSON, I can't find the way to skip the first 3 nodes and access to the data in an iteration:

```
[
   {
      "Table":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "DESC":"Sports",
            "ORDER":1,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "DESC":"Math",
            "ORDER":2,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "DESC":"English",
            "ORDER":3,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I already tried something like this `data[0].[0].[0]` or `data[0].firstChild`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why would they work? They aren't even valid syntax. You have objects in an array in an object in an array - take it one layer at a time.

Comment: `data[0]["Table"][0]` etc...

Comment: thanks a lot @JMoravitz,

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this, I will write a generic function to get the first child if it's an array or an object:

```
function getFirstChild(o) {
  if (o instanceof Array) {
    return o[0];
  } else {
    return o[Object.keys(o)[0]];
  }
}
```

Based on the type, it'll send me the first array element or the object's first key element's value.

Then I'll do thrice what you wanna do:

```
// first level
var myData = getFirstChild(data);
// second level
myData = getFirstChild(myData);
// third level
myData = getFirstChild(myData);
```

And then use `myData`, which has the right value. This is just my assumption of what you wanted. There's a lot of room for improvement.

**Full Snippet**

```js
function getFirstChild(o) {
  if (o instanceof Array) {
    return o[0];
  } else {
    return o[Object.keys(o)[0]];
  }
}

var data = [
   {
      "Table":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "DESC":"Sports",
            "ORDER":1,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "DESC":"Math",
            "ORDER":2,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "DESC":"English",
            "ORDER":3,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         }
      ]
   }
];

// first level
var myData = getFirstChild(data);
// second level
myData = getFirstChild(myData);
// third level
myData = getFirstChild(myData);

console.log(myData);
```

Or if I understand, you need the array to loop through. Just do twice:

```js
function getFirstChild(o) {
  if (o instanceof Array) {
    return o[0];
  } else {
    return o[Object.keys(o)[0]];
  }
}

var data = [
   {
      "Table":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "DESC":"Sports",
            "ORDER":1,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "DESC":"Math",
            "ORDER":2,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "DESC":"English",
            "ORDER":3,
            "AVAILABLE":true
         }
      ]
   }
];

// first level
var myData = getFirstChild(data);
// second level
myData = getFirstChild(myData);

console.log(myData);
```